# Laravel 9's setter mutator throws an error but Laravel 8 style mutator does not

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Laravel 9+ has this new mutator format according to the docs:

```
public function fullName(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn() => trim($this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name),
        set: function (?string $value) {
            $names = explode(' ', $value);

            $this->attributes['first_name'] = array_shift($names);
            $this->attributes['last_name'] = implode(' ', $names);
        }
    );
}
```

In my model I have this:

```
protected $appends = ['full_name'];
```

However, if I try to save the value like this:

```
$model->full_name = 'John Doe';
$model->save();
```

Then I get the error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'full_name' in 'field list
```

However, if I use the old way to format mutator setter methods like this then there is no error:

```
public function setFullNameAttribute(?string $value): void
{
    $names = explode(' ', $value);

    $this->attributes['first_name'] = array_shift($names);
    $this->attributes['last_name'] = implode(' ', $names);
}
```

Why doesn't the new mutator format work when setting values?

Comment: Sidenote, the first part of someone's name preceding a space is not always their first name... My wife's first name has a space in it, and it's mildly infuriating how many pieces of software show her name as "Mary" instead of her _actual_ name... Why not just have separate fields for first name and last name so you don't leave it up to convention to get it correct? (Can't speak to why this doesn't work in Laravel 9; I haven't use the `set` version yet)

Comment: @krisgjika that is exactly the idea of using an attribute setter... that is exactly his issue...

Comment: Author, this may not make a difference at all, but try setting `public function fullName` to `protected function fullName`, see that the documentation uses `protected`, not `public`. I think that is your issue

Comment: @TimLewis the data that goes into the `first_name` and `last_name` fields is usually collected separately. However, some systems we communicate with only ask customers for their full name as a single input field. When that happens, we have to find a way to adapt it to our system which stores each name part separately. I understand your frustration with that, but unfortunately those occurrences are out of our control.

Comment: @matiaslauriti tried setting it to protected and same error. I have other mutators that are public and they don't have any issue. Bizarrely it is only this one that sets based on the full name. However, you are correct that they should technically be protected, so I will be changing that going forward regardless.

Comment: All good! I see this happen a lot, where systems have a "Full Name" field (or simply "Name"), and they extrapolate what they believe is a First and Last name from that single field. It's almost always wrong (although some split on space and take the last part, which you could do here), but it's the nature of software development and names. [This article](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) is a pretty good summary about how names are such a pain for IT system. Cheers!